# Get the row and column for empty cell using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-handling

I am trying to fetch xls file which contains empty cells. I need to validate the xls file using pandas to get row and column position

[image: This is the excel sheet]

Expected output:

The row 2, col 2 has empty value  [OR]
Tenant ID is not found for Account1

Comment: use isnull() in pandas

Comment: If the below solution helped, please consider accepting it (tick on left) so other users know.

Answer (score 7):

Try this to obtain a list of Account Names with no Tenant Id:

```
res = df.loc[df['Tenant ID'].isnull(), 'Account Name'].tolist()
```

Alternatively, to filter your dataframe for rows where Tenant Id is empty:

```
df = df.loc[df['Tenant ID'].isnull(), :]
```

**Explanation**

- `.loc` accessor lets you specify row and column by Boolean arrays *or* label.
- For row filter, we use a Boolean array via `pd.Series.isnull` to identify rows where Tenant Id is blank.
- For column filter, we can use 'Account Name' and output to list via `pd.Series.tolist`.